# How to make SCons not include the base dir in zip files?

Tags: python, zip, scons

SCons provides a Zip builder to produce zip files from groups of files.
For example, suppose we have a folder `foo` that looks like this:

```
foo/
foo/blah.txt
```

and we create the zip file `foo.zip` from a folder `foo`:

```
env.Zip('foo.zip', 'foo/')
```

This produces a zip file:

```
$ unzip -l foo.zip
Archive:  foo.zip
  foo/
  foo/foo.txt
```

However, suppose we are using a `VariantDir` of bar, which contains foo:

```
bar/
bar/foo/
bar/foo/foo.txt
```

Because we are in a `VariantDir`, we still use the same command to create the zip file, even though it has slightly different effects:

```
env.Zip('foo.zip', 'foo/')
```

This produces the zip file:

```
$ unzip -l bar/foo.zip
Archive:  bar/foo.zip
  bar/foo/
  bar/foo/foo.txt
```

The problem is extra `bar/` prefix for each of the files within the zip. If this was not SCons, the simple solution would be to cd into `bar` and call zip from within there with something like `cd bar; zip -r foo.zip foo/`. However, this is weird/difficult with SCons, and at any rate seems very un-SCons-like. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a SCons Builder which accomplishes this task. We can use the standard Python zipfile to make the zip files. We take advantage of `zipfile.write`, which allows us to specify a file to add, as well as what it should be called within the zip:

```
zf.write('foo/bar', 'bar') # save foo/bar as bar
```

To get the right paths, we use `os.path.relpath` with the path of the base file to find the path to the overall file.

Finally, we use `os.walk` to walk through contents of directories that we want to add, and call the previous two functions to add them, correctly, to the final zip.

```
import os.path
import zipfile

def zipbetter(target, source, env):
    # Open the zip file with appending, so multiple calls will add more files
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(str(target[0]), 'a', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for s in source:
        # Find the path of the base file
        basedir = os.path.dirname(str(s))
        if s.isdir():
            # If the source is a directory, walk through its files
            for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(str(s)):
                for fname in filenames:
                    path = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
                    if os.path.isfile(path):
                        # If this is a file, write it with its relative path
                        zf.write(path, os.path.relpath(path, basedir))
        else:
            # Otherwise, just write it to the file
            flatname = os.path.basename(str(s))
            zf.write(str(s), flatname)
    zf.close()

# Make a builder using the zipbetter function, that takes SCons files
zipbetter_bld = Builder(action = zipbetter,
                        target_factory = SCons.Node.FS.default_fs.Entry,
                        source_factory = SCons.Node.FS.default_fs.Entry)

# Add the builder to the environment
env.Append(BUILDERS = {'ZipBetter' : zipbetter_bld})
```

Call it just like the normal SCons `Zip`:

```
env.ZipBetter('foo.zip', 'foo/')
```

Answer (score 2):

Using construct variable ‘ZIPROOT’

Answer (score 1):

Directories can indeed be a challenge with SCons. There are a couple of different ways you can specify the directory of the files to include in the Zip() file as follows, assuming the files are 'in project':

1. relative to the root project dir, prepending the path with '#'. This option will include the complete directory, like you mentioned
2. relative to a particular SConscript file. Either specify files in the same directory, or specify a subdirectory relative to the SConscript.

Sounds like you want the second option. Do you have a SConscript file in the same dir that you want to zip, `foo` in your case? This should work even for the variant_dir.

Comment: The problem isn't specifying the directory of the zip file, it's the directory that I want to add... And no, I don't have an SConscript file in the directory. The directory is being created when I build, and then I want to zip one of the created folders in-place.

Comment: @Xymostech, Right, I reworded the answer. I understood that you were referring to the files/dir to be added to the zip. Instead of specifying the directory, you can use the target returned from the builder. If you include the SConscript, I can take a look.

Comment: I've tried using the return from the builder, and that still doesn't work. Here's the code: https://gist.github.com/2822868

Comment: @Xymostech, You can also play around with the Package() builder, setting the PACKAGETYPE to zip. I'll test this and see if it helps.

Comment: @Xymostech, BTW you live in my absolute favorite city ever :) I used to live in Louisville, but had to move for family reasons.